# iGraph - Spacing between verticies

Tags: r, igraph

I have a dataset called data. The data is not that important, but every interaction has a name. I want to create a graph in iGraph with the following code:

```
tab <- count(data, B, S, K)
factors <- table(interaction(tab$B, tab$K),interaction(tab$S,tab$K))
graph1 <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(factors)
plot(graph1, vertex.size = 40, layout = layout.bipartite)
```

However, I get the following:

[image: Graph]

All the names of interactions are completely mixed together. I can make it a little more readable by lowering the `vertex.size`, but I want to find a solution to my problem.

I want to create more space between the verticies, but I cannot seem to find the right way.
I have tried creating a manual graph by using `tkplot`, but it is annoying that I manually have to sort them each time.

Best regards

Comment: Yes,  the data is important.  How can we try things out without your data?  Please use `dput(graph1)` and paste the results into your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Well I thought there was an easy command to create more spacing, so sorry about that. I have pasted the results here: https://pastebin.com/N8aT0pqu

Comment: You can get some improvement by using `vertex.size = 15, vertex.label.cex = 0.8` in your plot statement.  However, there is so much text on the upper line that you will probably have to use a custom layout to separate the labels.   BTW,  were you aware that in your current plot, two nodes ( #5 & 6) are plotted in the same place?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I actually were not aware of that. Thank you for the heads up. I will probably have to manually create the plot using `tkplot(graph1)` then.

Comment: I notice that you say "it is annoying that I manually have to sort them each time."  Are you aware that after using `tkplot`,  you can save the position of the nodes and then use it again later?  Take a look at `1tkplot.getcoords`